# How to set the background color in the JTextPane and get the HTML code?

Tags: java, swing, background-color, jtextpane

I am using Java swing to produce a text editor, using a `JTextPane`,But I found `StyledEditorKit class` has not a method  to set the background color.

Then i use this idea to set the background color:

```
SimpleAttributeSet aSet = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setBackground(aSet, color);
StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
doc.setCharacterAttributes(textPane.getSelectionStart(),textPane.getSelectionEnd()-textPane.getSelectionStart(), aSet, false);
```

It can display background color in `JTextPane`,
but not by `textPane.GetText()`
Get the HTML code.

Then I also found an idea:

```
class bgAction extends StyledEditorKit.StyledTextAction {

    public bgAction(String arg0) {
        super(arg0);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        JEditorPane editor = getEditor(arg0);
        try {

            String selectedText = editor.getSelectedText();

            HTMLDocument document = (HTMLDocument) this.getStyledDocument(editor);

            System.out.println(document == TextView.this.document);
            document.remove(editor.getSelectionStart(),selectedText.length());

            HTMLEditorKit et = (HTMLEditorKit) this.getStyledEditorKit(editor);

            et.insertHTML(document, editor.getSelectionStart(), ""+ selectedText + "", 0, 0, HTML.Tag.SPAN);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

But `insertHTML()` method does not work.
Is this where I went wrong?

Is there a way to set the background color in the `JTextPane` and get the HTML code?

Answer (score -1):

Use this code snippet

```
                     JTextPane p=new JTextPane();
         p.setContentType("text/html");
         p.setStyledDocument(new HTMLDocument());

         frame.getContentPane().add(p);
         p.setText("<html><p>This is some text in a paragraph.</p></html>");
         System.out.println(p.getText());
```

Comment: this code is the same with my first code snippet,can display background color in JTextPane, but cant by textPane.getText() Get the HTML code.

Comment: USe textPane.getDocument().getText() kind of method.

Comment: textPane.getDocument().getText() only can get text, but i want get the HTML code, and textPane.getText() can.

Comment: How it's related to background color?

Comment: @StanislavL He is capable  of set background color. But he was not able to get the html code.

Comment: @SanjayaLiyanage he knows the getText() method. His problem is the background set is not reflected in the result html string. So your comment has nothing related to the fix.